# computercraft variable in if statment

Tags: lua, computercraft

I have a little problem I´m new to the Lua and ComputerCraft. so my problem I think is that I´m too stupid to code a variable change that's in an if statement I will post my code down hope that you can help me with that problem thx

```
mon = peripheral.wrap("top")
modem = peripheral.wrap("right")
mon.clear()
mon.setCursorPos(1,2)
mon.blit("Pulverizer","0000000000","dddddddddd")
redstone.setOutput("right", true)
Pulverizer = true
mon.setCursorPos(1,4)
mon.write("Furnice","0000000","ddddddd")
redstone.setOutput("left", true)
local Furnice = true
mon.setCursorPos(1,6)
mon.write("Injection Chamber","00000000000000000","ddddddddddddddddd")
local Injection_Chamber = true
redstone.setOutput("top",true)
mon.setCursorPos(1,8)
mon.write("Metalurgig InFuser","000000000000000000","dddddddddddddddddd")
local Metalurgig_InFuser = true
redstone.setOutput("bottom", true)
while true do
  event,side,x,y = os.pullEvent("monitor_touch")


  if x > 1 and x < 11 and y == 2 and Pulverizer == true then
    mon.setCursorPos(1,2)
    mon.clearLine()
    mon.blit("Pulverizer","0000000000","eeeeeeeeee")
    redstone.setOutput("right", false)
    Pulverizer = false

 elseif x > 1 and x < 11 and y == 2 and Pulverizer == false then
   mon.setCoursorPos(1,2)
   mon.clearLine()
   mon.blit("Pulverizer","0000000000","dddddddddd")
   redstone.setOutput("right", true)
   Pulverizer = true
  end
end
```

the link for the Pastebin : [link to code](https://pastebin.com/06WmfbjJ)

so the problem is in this part of the code

```
if x > 1 and x < 11 and y == 2 and Pulverizer == true then
mon.setCursorPos(1,2)
mon.clearLine()
mon.blit("Pulverizer","0000000000","eeeeeeeeee")
redstone.setOutput("right", false)
Pulverizer = false
```

the Pulverizer variable don't want to change from true to false so this code cant get activated right now

```
   elseif x > 1 and x < 11 and y == 2 and Pulverizer == false then
   mon.setCoursorPos(1,2)
   mon.clearLine()
   mon.blit("Pulverizer","0000000000","dddddddddd")
   redstone.setOutput("right", true)
   Pulverizer = true
```

and I don't know why 
also here is a video link from in-game footage so as you can see in the video it turns red but doesn't turn green anymore

https://youtu.be/R4dpN-egnwY

Comment: we'll need t know what happens, and what you want to happen,

Comment: I updated it maybe it's now a little bit clearer what should happen it´s basically should change the variable Pulverizer from true to false that the elseif statement can get activated but this doesn't happen what happened it´s basically a switch button and it should switch when I click the button on the computercraft monitor @ratchetfreak a

Comment: I saw the video and noticed the low framerate. Add a `sleep(0.2)` before the last `end` and see if it changes anything. What could be happening is `Pulverizer` being toggled too fast for it to be noticeable on screen. This is especially relevant since you're doing this in multiplayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will solve your problem but it's worth a try to debug this.
Just for good practice I'd recommend that when you define Pulverizer on line 7, set it to a local by using `local Pulverizer = true`. Probably won't make a difference but it's good practice. In my experience it's also good practice to avoid using variables with capitalized first letters.

Secondly, try re-working your `if` block into 2 blocks like this:

```
if x > 1 and x < 11 and y == 2 then
  --Put some output message here or something so that you can see that it's entered this block of code and detected the cursor properly
    mon.setCursorPos(1,2)
    mon.clearLine()
  if Pulverizer == true then
    --Put another output message here so that you can see that Pulverizer is being evaluated as true
    mon.blit("Pulverizer","0000000000","eeeeeeeeee")
  elseif Pulverizer == false then
    --Put one last output message here so that if Pulverizer is being evaluated as false you'll know
    mon.blit("Pulverizer","0000000000","dddddddddd")
  end
Pulverizer = not Pulverizer
redstone.setOutput("right", Pulverizer)
end
```

If you insert a debug message in the places where I've put comments (the greyed out lines) then it should help you narrow down on the problem because you can see which if blocks are being entered and which are not. Another good idea would be to put in some code immediately after you do `Pulverizer = true` or `Pulverizer = false` that will show the value of `Pulverizer`.

I'm not super familiar with Computercraft's specific syntax so I'm not sure if you could display a message in chat or just on the monitor for debugging purposes, but you get the idea. Whenever you have a problem you can't quite narrow down, try putting debug messages around in your code so you can see exactly what's happening and work from there. If you find out any more information, feel free to leave a comment and I'll check back and see if I can help any more.

Hopefully you find this helpful, have a great weekend!

Comment: Also, some of the code in both `if` blocks is basically the same. `mon.setCoursorPos(1,2)` and `mon.clearLine()` could be moved under the bounds check while `redstone.setOutput("right", true)` and `redstone.setOutput("right", false)` could be moved to inbetween the two `end` keywords in the form of `redstone.setOutput("right", Pulverizer)`, since it shares the same boolean values with `Pulverizer`.

Comment: Well now I just feel stupid, not sure why I didn't suggest that stuff earlier.
Your suggestions have been added to the post. I also added a line to invert Pulverizer.
If we're REALLY optimizing I'd prefer to use ternary comparisons to if blocks for single-line stuff like that.

Comment: Yes, we could use a ternary comparison. `mon.blit("Pulverizer", "0000000000", Pulverizer and "eeeeeeeeee" or "dddddddddd")`. Or we could use `if Pulverizer then mon.blit("Pulverizer", "0000000000", "eeeeeeeeee") else mon.blit("Pulverizer", "0000000000", "dddddddddd") end`. But this should appear after negating `Pulverizer`.